# VB - Export Outlook Calendar to Excel including 'Meeting Organizer'

Tags: vb.net, outlook, export-to-excel

I have a lengthy bit of code that extracts information from an Outlook Calendar to an Excel File and alls the user has to do is simply choose a date range, however as useful as that is for one user, if there were to be multiple users then I need someway of extracting the 'MeetingOrganizer' as it is called when using the 'Import/Export' Wizard to extract it to a CSV File, however I cannot work out what I need to add, here is the relevant bits of code that I need to add it to, thanks for any help you can give me:

```
'Write Excel Column Headers
            With excWks
                .Cells(1, 1) = "Subject"
                .Cells(1, 2) = "Location"
                .Cells(1, 3) = "MeetingOrganizer" 'Does not work
                .Cells(1, 4) = "StartDate"
                .Cells(1, 5) = "FinishDate"
                .Cells(1, 6) = "StartTime"
                .Cells(1, 7) = "FinishTime"
                .Cells(1, 8) = "Hours"
            End With



> xcWks.Cells(lngRow, 1) = olkApt.Subject
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 2) = olkApt.Location
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 3) = olkApt.MeetingOrganizer 'Does not work
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 4) = Format(olkApt.Start, "mm/dd/yyyy")
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 5) = Format(olkApt.End, "mm/dd/yyyy")
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 6) = Format(olkApt.Start, "hh:nn ampm")
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 7) = Format(olkApt.End, "hh:nn ampm")
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 8) = DateDiff("n", olkApt.Start, olkApt.End) / 60
>                     excWks.Cells(lngRow, 8).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

the main thing I am after is the specific name that is given to the meeting organiser. so as you can see Location and Subject are 2 obvious examples, and no matter what I try I seem to be getting no where, hopefully someone will have worked this out already...

Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like you need to repeat the code for each recipient. You can use the for loop for example to iterate over all recipients in the code. Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: its always going to be the same Recipient as its there unique calendar... and that data is submitted into a database from this excel file. Do you have any examples of what you mean? ive not used VB really before, more of a C# person, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
    .Cells(1, 4) = "User"

    excWks.Cells(lngRow, 4) = strLst
```